# Custom UIView wrap-around

Tags: objective-c, uiview, datepicker, word-wrap, visual-effects

I have an NSArray of custom UIViews (ACTileView). They act as one row. I would like to be able to slide them left or right (which is currently already possible) but have the wrap-around (to create the effect of endless "Tiles" much like the UIDatePickerView on the iPhone). I don't have any ideas anymore on how I can achieve this effect.

Help would be greatly appreciated
kind regards, JNK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once did something similar with 50+ views one could page through. Clearly, for memory reasons you should not load all those views into an array if they are not visible.

So what I did was to have the amount of visible views +2 on each side in my array. Which each change of the position, I would update the array by popping one view off one side and adding the next one on the other side.

I put this logic into the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` delegate method of the `UIScrollView`, but you could also put it into `scrollViewDidScroll` and then check for the necessary adjustments of views.

You can re-assign an new `NSArray` each time and discard the old one, or do everything in a `MSMutableArray`.

If your views are all visible at the same time, use this method and just double the chain.

Comment: There are between 3-5 views in one array. All of the views are visible. The leftmost view is supposed to appear on the right (and left at the same time) if you slide left.

Comment: See the last line of my answer.